# Horizontal LinearLayout space between items without padding left and right

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I need space between items in LinearLayout without padding on the sides.

This image will explain it:

[image]

This is the XML:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rateOneStar"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star"
            app:tint="@color/ratingStarInactive" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rateTwoStar"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star"
            app:tint="@color/ratingStarInactive" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rateThreeStar"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star"
            app:tint="@color/ratingStarInactive" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rateFourStar"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star"
            app:tint="@color/ratingStarInactive" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rateFiveStar"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star"
            app:tint="@color/ratingStarInactive" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In the part that you tell us to ignore, you should have put what was your best attempt to achieve this.

Comment: Use coordinatorLayout. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/coordinatorlayout/widget/CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: better solution

Setting layoutWeight on edge views would remove padding around them.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/requested"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/original">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rateOneStar"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_round_credit_card_24"
            app:tint="@color/colorLightBlack" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rateTwoStar"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_round_credit_card_24"
            app:tint="@color/colorLightBlack" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rateThreeStar"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_round_credit_card_24"
            app:tint="@color/colorLightBlack" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rateFourStar"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_round_credit_card_24"
            app:tint="@color/colorLightBlack" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rateFiveStar"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_round_credit_card_24"
            app:tint="@color/colorLightBlack" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: This way a part of first and last items gets cut out

Comment: Then lower margin value on like -6dp. You could also use layoutWeight=0 on first and last views

Comment: This would only reduce the width of LinearLayout

Comment: First solution I wrote should work, and can't find a reason why would you care so much if it brings the right result.. I don't know for what solution are you looking then.. Switch to constraint layout then

Comment: What I want to archieve is clearly explained with the image, your "solutions" don't result in what I try to archieve

Comment: Clearly, you haven't even tried out the solutions. Your LinearLayout width is fixed to 240dp so it can't be reduced.. Both solutions work and achieve requested result

Comment: Ok adding android:layout_weight="0" to first, last AND mid one works, it probably wouldn't with only 4 items though but I let it pass :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this solution now:

https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Instead of LinearLayout:

```
    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:justifyContent="space_between">
```